# Using Text::CSV to print a line on a csv files based on variables content

Tags: perl

My script is fairly large but I'll simplify the code here.
Suppose that I create a CSV and I write the header like this:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary => 1}, eol => "\n");
open(my $out, ">", "$dir/out.csv") or die $!; #create
$out->print("CodeA,CodeB,Name,Count,Pos,Orientation\n"); #I write the header
```

Suppose that I got the some values stored in different variables and I want to write those variables as a line in the CSV.
I cannot figure out how, because on the Text::CSV documentation the print is not clearly explained, there's no direct examples and i don't know what an array ref is.

Comment: Have you read the manual for [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV)?  Which parts of it don't you understand?  Do you know what an array ref is?

Comment: This is the point. I can't understand the print and i don't know what an array ref is.

Comment: Then you should probably read [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) first.

Comment: If you're having difficulty understanding the documentation, it's sensible to (a) link to it, and (b) explain that you don't understand what it says. For example, near the start of `print`, it says _It expects an array ref as input (not an array!)_  If you don't understand that, say so. It makes it clear you know a bit about how to find information, and you have done some research, but you have a problem because you don't understand the terminology used.  (It isn't the clearest manual page in the world either; the opening sentence for `print` is requires a lot of knowledge of the module.)

Comment: Thank you very much i'm going to edit the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a trivial example of using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) to write a CSV file.  It generates a header line and a data line, and does so from fixed data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, eol => $/ })
    or die "Failed to create a CSV handle: $!";

my $filename = "output.csv";

open my $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "failed to create $filename: $!";

my(@heading) = ("CodeA", "CodeB", "Name", "Count", "Pos", "Orientation");
$csv->print($fh, \@heading);    # Array ref!

my(@datarow) = ("A", "B", "Abelone", 3, "(6,9)", "NW");
$csv->print($fh, \@datarow);    # Array ref!

close $fh or die "failed to close $filename: $!";
```

The row of data is collected in an array — I used `@heading` and `@datarow`.  If I was outputting several rows, each row could be collected or created in `@datarow` and then output.  The first argument to `$csv->print` should be the I/O handle — here, `$fh`, a file handle for the output file.  The second should be an array ref.  Using `\@arrayname` is one way of creating an array ref; the input routines for the Text::CSV module also create and return array refs.

Note the difference between the notation used here in the `Text::CSV->new` call and the notation used in your example.  Also note that your `$out->print("…");` call is using the basic file I/O and nothing to do with Text::CSV.  Contrast with `$csv->print($fh, …)`.

The rest of the code is more or less boilerplate.

#### `output.csv`

```
CodeA,CodeB,Name,Count,Pos,Orientation
A,B,Abelone,3,"(6,9)",NW
```

Note that the value with an embedded comma was surrounded by quotes by the Text::CSV module.  The other values did not need quotes so they did not get them.  You can tweak the details of the CSV output format with the options to `Text::CSV->new`.

Comment: Mentioning `eol => $/ ` saved my day, otherwise it writes in first line.

Answer (score 3):

For the headers you can use

```
$status = $csv->print ($out,[qw(CodeA CodeB Name Count Pos Orientation)]);
```

and for a row of values use

```
$status = $csv->print ($out,[$valueA,$valueB,$valueName,$valueCount,$valuePos,$valueOrientation]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
  binary    => 1,
  auto_diag => 1,
  sep_char  => ','    # not really needed as this is the default
});

my $sum = 0;
open(my $data, '<:encoding(utf8)', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
while (my $fields = $csv->getline( $data )) {
  $sum += $fields->[2];
}
if (not $csv->eof) {
  $csv->error_diag();
}
close $data;
print "$sum\n";
```

Comment: Just plain code isnt a complete answer. Please have a look at [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was how to **write** a CSV file. You show how to **read** it.